# SSIS job runs successfully but doesn't load data

Tags: ssms, sql-server-agent, proxy

I am running a job from SQL Server Agent and the job runs successfully. However it doesn't load any data (in my case Excel files from a local folder). I created a new Proxy Account to run this job but it still doesn't help. I checked that the proxy user has SYSADMIN rights and also permissions to access the Excel files from the folder.

I run the package from Visual Studio and it runs successfully and the files are loaded. This is done manually every time.

We want to fix this issue. Can someone please help me with this. I can share any more information as needed.

Comment: How many steps in job configuration? You might have configured the job to run at step 2(start step). May be that's why it didn't run the Step1 (SSIS package). If every thing look good in job config. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518494/sql-job-completes-successfully-but-does-not-execute-packages

Comment: We have 3 steps in job configuration. I tried running with step 2 3 and even 1. It still doesn't work. I don't know what I am doing wrong. we have a foreach loop as well. I also created a new proxy and gave permissions to access the folder which contains files. Thanks I will take a look at the link you shared.

Comment: when I looked at ssidb, this is the warning message I get. "Warning: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty"

Comment: Check your local path? If you run the package on the SQL Server, the files need to be in that LOCAL PATH on the SQL Server. like C:\Users\Desktop\Folder\..

Comment: Check this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aedc934b-5346-4e50-8448-a6905ee15d8f/warning-the-for-each-file-enumerator-is-empty-the-for-each-file-enumerator-did-not-find-any-files?forum=sqlintegrationservices